# How do you display text using formatting in the form of a MVC3 view?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a MVC3 web project that I am trying to display text from an xml doc in the form area of one of my views.
I would like the xml to be displayed with color coding and pretty print indenting like the xml text that is displayed when you open an xml file using IE.

Currenty I am using the `@Html.Display("xmlfiletext")`. 
The text is displayed as mono color with no new lines or carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of [syntax highlighting plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/) that allow you to achieve that. [Google prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is just one example.